# how to copy all *.bak files from Directory A to Directory B?

Tags: c#, winforms

How to copy all `*.bak` files from `Directory A` to `Directory B`?

Comment: can you post what you have done so far?

Comment: Also, are they on the same volume (drive)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do what you need:

```
string dirA = @"C:\";
string dirB = @"D:\";

string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(dirA);

foreach (string s in files) {
    if (System.IO.Path.GetExtension(s).equals("bak")) {
        System.IO.File.Copy(s, System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName), true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not going to give you the full solution, but check out [Directory.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f.aspx) (which takes a search pattern) and [File.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cfw35a.aspx).

Those two methods are everything you need.

Comment: OP probably wants File.Copy, since thats what is used in the post.

Comment: Not sure why this post got upvoted so quickly when the OP obviously asked for the solution, not for a reference. Sometimes I think SO was built on a 'the rich get richer' scheme.

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer SO is not a place you run to to make others do your work.

Comment: @alexn: I think that's quite obvious. But that idea doesn't mean SO is a site where your rank should be determined by your inability to give the requested answer. Additionally, the OP has a couple hundred rep. It's not like he just joined to ask the question.

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer I think my answer is completely valid. I can't see why we always must provide a fully working solution. I gave him pretty much everything he needs to complete his task. Sure, i could have given him the full code, but why?

Comment: @alexn: Your answer is "valid" in much the same way that if you asked me for a car, and I gave you all the pieces. You have a car, put it together yourself. I bet you're one satisfied customer. Hope you don't plan on needing to use it in the next year.

Comment: @freeasinbeer Actually the OP gained all his rep from asking 71 questions **many of which follow the same How to .... title**

Comment: @The_Scrum_Meister: Haha, touche!

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer you're comparing apples to pears. This is not a shop where you go buy your solutions. People invest their free time to help others. As i said, i can't understand why we always need to give full solutions, but hints to make it yourself.

Comment: @alexn: My point is, if you don't want to help someone, or answer their question exactly, that's fine. Don't. But it doesn't seem fair that you would earn a much greater amount of rep for your "pseudo-answer" than someone who puts in a greater amount of effort.

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer i completely agree on that :)

Comment: linking to relevant documentation should be enough for any competent developer work with.  There is no need to give a full, working solution for every trivial problem that comes through here.

Answer (score 2):

There's two ways, the pure C# way:

```
var items = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("Directory A", "*.bak", System.IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
foreach(String filePath in items)
{
    var newFile = System.IO.Path.Combine("Directory B", System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath));
    System.IO.File.Copy(filePath, newFile);
}
```

The `robocopy` way:

```
var psi = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
psi.FileName = @"C:\windows\system32\robocopy.exe";
psi.Arguments = "Directory A Directory B *.bak";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(psi);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this link http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Execute_Command_in_CSharp.aspx

to execute

```
xcopy /y /f PathOfA\*.bak PathOfB\
```

Comment: How do you know the OP is running on Windows?

Comment: cause the tags are C# and WinForms :)

Answer (score 0):

My improvement on above suggestions:

```
public static void CopyFilesWithExtension(string src, string dst, string extension)
{
    string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(src);

    foreach (string s in files)
    {
         if (System.IO.Path.GetExtension(s).Equals(extension))
         {
             var filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(s);
             System.IO.File.Copy(s, System.IO.Path.Combine(dst, filename));
         }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Utils.CopyFilesWithExtension(@"C:\src_folder",@"C:\dst_folder",".csv");
```